# JAXB Adapter is not picked up

Tags: java, jaxb, adapter

I have a pojo item that I need to serialize.
Primitives of pojo have a "logical null"    (when primitive equals to some specific value it's null).
The requirement of serialization is to return it as null, therefor I must create adapters where I wrapp primitives with objects and in case, the primitive is "null" set the object to null.

The problem is that adapter is not picked up. The wiring is done via package-info.

Object:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Item {
    String name;
    int id;
    long price;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public long getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(long price) {
        this.price = price;
    }


    @XmlTransient
    public boolean isIdNull(){
        return id==-99888899;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public boolean isPriceNull(){
        return price==-1775445454544L;
    }
```

This is the wrapper class with adapter.

```
@XmlType(name = "item")
public class ItemAdapterWrapper {

    String name;
    Integer id;
    Long price;

    @XmlElement
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Long getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Long price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static class ItemAdapter extends XmlAdapter<ItemAdapterWrapper, Item> {

        @Override
        public Item unmarshal(ItemAdapterWrapper v) throws Exception {
            if (v == null) {
                return null;
            }

            Item item = new Item();

            if (v.getName() != null)
                item.setName(v.getName());

            if (v.getPrice() != null)
                item.setPrice(v.getPrice());

            if (v.getId() != null)
                item.setId(v.getId());

            return item;
        }

        @Override
        public ItemAdapterWrapper marshal(Item v) throws Exception {
            if (v == null) {
                return null;
            }

            ItemAdapterWrapper ItemAdapterWrapper = new ItemAdapterWrapper();

            if (!v.isIdNull()) {
                ItemAdapterWrapper.setId(v.getId());
            }

            if (!v.isPriceNull()) {
                ItemAdapterWrapper.setPrice(v.getPrice());
            }

            ItemAdapterWrapper.setName(v.getName());

            return ItemAdapterWrapper;
        }

    }
```

package-info.java:

```
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
        @javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=ItemAdapterWrapper.ItemAdapter.class, type=Item.class) })  
package org.datatypes;
```

All are in same package.
When I try to marshal:

```
Item item = new Item();
item.setName("XXX");
item.setId(4);

StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Item.class);
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
m.marshal(item, output);
System.out.println(output.toString());
```

Adapter class is not triggered (I set breakpoints) and original Item is getting serialized.

What did I miss?

It's not like the existing question, as I don't have annotation over pojo, and I use package-info.

Comment: File name is `package-info.java`, not `package-info`, and must contain a `package` statement. It is that `package` statement that is annotated.

Comment: You can use @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ItemAdapter.class) on the class level of Item class in your case. And you don't need ItemAdapterWrapper at all.

Comment: @Anton Vetrov, I can't modify Item class therefor I can't add new annotations there.

Comment: @Andreas, sorry it was a typo, package is annotated and it's package-info.java

Comment: @yuris But your variant will work only if Item class will be a member of some other class, for instance RootItem class. And if you marshal this RooItem  you will obtain your modified Item.